# which is the best javascript animation framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, open-source, gsap

I need a javascript animation framework which has the best performance. I am thinking to use http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/ this one, it gives performance 20x vs jquery animate.

i need support in all major browsers, so css3 based animations is not solution for me.

Comment: i think it depends on your usecase. i would also take a look at [morpheus](https://github.com/ded/morpheus) which is purely based on css3

Comment: i need support in all major browsers, so css3 based animations is not solution for me.

Comment: Google, and look whichever lib/toolkit fits your requirements best. Also read the FAQ, to understand why this isn't the place for this question...

Comment: I already did this, thank for reminding me that google exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greensock is good, but I think zepto.js is also a good choice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Zepto uses CSS3 transitions for all animation, so it won't work in IE9 or earlier. GreenSock's works well in all major browsers. You might want to check out http://www.greensock.com/why-gsap/ where it explains some specific real-world reasons why it's a good option. Obviously it's faster than pretty much any other JS framework, but it's also better than CSS3 transitions/animations for reasons beyond compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html Check it out and decide yourself. Its a performance test of some of animation engines.

And GSAP seems to be the best.